# Exporting data from Cloud SQL to excel using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to **export cloud SQL data to excel sheet** without copying it to Google Spreadsheet using **Google Apps Script**.

Since there is limitation of Google Spreadsheet of 4,00,000 cells, I am looking to export data directly to Excel sheet rather than copying it to Spreadsheet.

I specifically want to implement it using Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can serve a CSV file, which you can set up to be downloaded. I attached a sample script to show you how it might work.

**Warning**: Because this is a Comma Separated Values file, you must ensure that your data does **not** contain commas.

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (parseInt(e.parameter.download) == 1) {
    var someData = [{name:"Jerry",
                     age:27,
                     married:true},
                    {name:"Harry",
                     age:16,
                     married:false},
                    {name:"Gary",
                     age:65,
                     married:true},
                    {name:"Larry",
                     age:41,
                     married:false}];
    var output = "Name,Age,Married?\n";
    for (var i in someData) {
      output += someData[i].name + ","+someData[i].age + ","+someData[i].married + "\n";
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(output).downloadAsFile("data.csv");
  } else {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var anchor = app.createAnchor("Download the CSV File",ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?download=1");
    app.add(anchor);
    return app;
  }
}
```

**Note**: Because you are looking for such a large file, this actually might not work. Your script will probably time out. Suppose each entry that you have is 100 bytes, then you will have a 400 MB excel file? That is just large in general.

Comment: Thanks for the script. I have around 43 columns in my table and around 1,00,000 rows. There is possibility of exceeding row count as the application starts working.
For review purpose, I need to export data. This will not work with spreadsheet for the cell count limitation. Can you please suggest some other alternate.

Comment: My answer is an alternate. Download as CSV.

Comment: So will i get time out on trying to download the database content as csv?

Comment: It is possible, yes. You are working with a large dataset. You will probably have to split the data and work with some of it at a time (say, 20,000 entries at a time).

Answer (score 0):

Could avoid limits of g apps and spreadsheets by using odbc/jdbc directly from excel https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external

Comment: Can you please explain it more. Any example to refer?